# Pointing domain to AWS Classic ELB DNS Name without using Amazon route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have a domain example.com. 
I want to point this domain to my AWS internet-facing classic ELB public DNS (my-elb-123456789.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com) without using Amazon Route 53.
How should i configure elb DNS in my domain (example.com) DNS records as a CNAME?
Then what is my 'A' record in DNS configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any DNS provider to direct subdomain traffic to an AWS load balancer. Create a CNAME record that has the value set to the ELB CNAME. This has to be a subdomain with most DNS providers - the www subdomain would be most common. [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html).

Setting the domain apex to point at the ELB is more difficult. You can't use an A record as the IP of the ELB changes, and you can't put a CNAME at the domain apex as it's against the DNS specification.

Some providers let you create something similar to a CNAME at the domain apex, including [Route53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html) and [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168986-How-do-I-add-a-Amazon-ELB-Elastic-Load-Balancing-record-to-Cloudflare-), in a way that meets the DNS specification.

If your provider won't let you set a CNAME at the domain apex you'll have to create an A record and some kind of redirection. Some options include:

- A t2.nano EC2 instance with Nginx returning a 301 redirect
- CloudFlare and a page rule (though if you're using CloudFlare it's better to use the solution above)
- [S3 bucket redirection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) (only works on http, not https)

Comment: If your DNS provider *does* let you put a CNAME at the Apex of a zone, then you have a DNS provider that doesn't understand how DNS works.  This is an invalid configuration, always and everywhere.  Cloudflare doesn't create a real CNAME record.  Their "CNAME flattening" feature actually creates an A record and does a back-end lookup, similar in behavior to a Route 53 alias.  Some providers call this an "ANAME" which is not a real RR type, but is similar to what Cloudflare is doing.

Comment: There are multiple instances where using a CNAME for ELB will not work. Some service require an A record and not a CNAME. The advantage of Route 53 is that it allows "alias" records that appear to be A records, but in the backend point to another AWS service. This is the case for both ADFS SSO, and E-mail servers (to avoid spam filtering).